# my first iPhone app and i'm stuck

Tags: iphone, text, floating-point

i've decided to give this iPhone App development a kick. to help add perspective to this i've never programmed in any form of C or for any anything on the Mac other than Applescript. i've created plenty of solutions using blends of Applescript, Classic ASP, Perl, even PostScript. i'm home brewed so i don't understand all the my Obj.xyz.blah.blee stuff, sorry ;-/

i need to...
1) take data from a field
2) convert it to a float
3) do some math
4) then plop the results in a label

i've gotten a version of this working where i pull the text from a filed and plop the results into a label upon clicking on a "Calculate" button, that was easy. so i know that points 1 and 4 are good. now for the tough part...

i've setup an initial version to ensure i can do points 3 and 4 by setting my float variables as static bits of data...

```
float float_DiameterA, float_DiameterB;
float myR1, myR2;

float_DiameterA = 20;
float_DiameterB = 5;

myR1=(float_DiameterA-float_DiameterB)/2;
myR2=1;

r1.text=[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myR1] stringValue];
r2.text=[[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myR2] stringValue];
a1.text = txtLength.text;
```

results : r1 displays "7.5" and r2 displays "1". this works perfectly BUT i need to take txtDiameterA.text and put it into float_DiameterA as a floating point.

here's what i've tried for step 2...

```
str_DiameterA = [txtDiameterA.text text];
float_DiameterA = [[str_DiameterA text] floatValue];
```

but that didn't work ;-/

i've even tried several versions of
    if(EOF == sscanf(str_DiameterA, "%f", &float_DiameterA)){
        //error
    };

and

```
float_DiameterA = sscanf(txtDiameterA.text, "%f", &f);
```

but none of those worked either. i think that's when i started to realize this wasn't C++ as i thought it was lol...

think you'll get the idea by now.

so...

**how do you take the input from txtDiameterA.text and convert into a float?** please don't tell me to use Root Beer instead of a Cola lol.

oh, here's a few more bits of information that might have some impact...

part of my .h file

```
IBOutlet UITextField *txtDiameterA;
IBOutlet UITextField *txtDiameterB;

IBOutlet UILabel *r1;
IBOutlet UILabel *r2;
```

i designed my UI using the Interface Builder.

**THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR YOUR ASSISTANCE!!! ;-)**

Comment: You will progress super fast if you buy, read and do the exercises in two books: Programming in Objective-C by Kochan and Beginning iPhone Development by Mark and LaMarche. I knew fewer languages than you, and now I have 2 small apps in the store with more on the way. Read and ask plenty of questions here as well. Good luck.

Comment: " i don't understand all the my Obj.xyz.blah.blee stuff, sorry " Oh, son, are you in for hard ride! You sound like a skilled scripter but willc2 is correct. If you don't get some fundamentals of the Apple API OOP down you're going to spend a lot of time spinning your wheels in the future. A few hours or even days spent now learning the basic will save days or even weeks of grief and frustration later on.

Comment: thanks for the feedback you two!

willc2, i'll go grab those two books, hope the wife doesn't freak cause i just picked up iPhone Application Dev for Dummies the other day. it was a leap of faith for me because i found that their old AppleScript book worked wonders for me.

TechZen, i know, i've heard that a few times from other true professionals. i'm game to try. have a suggestion on a book or something for me?

thanks again ;-)

Answer (score 2):

txtDiameterA is a [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html).  Looking at the docs we can see that the 'text' attribute of a UITextField returns an [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

NSString has a lovely method called floatValue that returns a float representation of the string!

So,

```
NSString *diameter = txtDiameterA.text;
float diameterAsFloat = [diameter floatValue];
```

gives you the value in your text field as a float.

Comment: I was SOOOO close lol... i had read something about this floatValue thing but missed the NSString part.

thanks SO much... tested and working! so much for playing EQ, i'll be building my app today!

thanks again! ;-)